# How do I run a bash script prompted by an html form?

Tags: bash, php

My current way of going about this is to use PHP exec

```
<?php

$filename = "log.txt";
$text = $_POST['form'];

$fp = fopen ($filename, "w");
if ($fp) {
    fwrite ($fp, $text);
    fclose ($fp);
    exec('/var/www/html/bash.sh');
header('Location: /next.html');
}
else {
    echo ("ERROR.");

}

?>
```

So I know the script is at least running because it writes to log.txt fine, but from what I can see nothing in bash.sh is actually running. Just on the command line if I run

> "exec sudo bash /full/path/bash.sh"

Then it executes it fine. I am not sure if this is a permission error, or what. Am I doing something wrong, or is there just a better way to do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At least three problems here:

- the code writes the form contents to a file named `log.txt` (in some unknown directory) and then executes the unrelated `/var/www/html/bash.sh`
- the code runs `/var/www/html/bash.sh` without specifying an interpreter, so it relies on a proper shebang in the script (and your external test specified the interpreter: `sudo bash ...`
- The script is run with the id of the server (www-data or somesuch) not with root.

Comment: log.txt and bash.sh are not supposed to be related, so I do not think that is the issue. The script begins with #!/bin/sh, so do I need to add sudo bash to the exec(); ? I am not sure how to fix the last thing you said. Any ideas?

Comment: *log.txt and bash.sh are not supposed to be related*: then how does the code from the form end up in bash.sh? *The script begins with #!/bin/sh* `/bin/sh` isn't `bash`. And instead of answering the comments, edit your question...